# Is there a move list for Arcstrider?

Tags: destiny-2

The [Arcstrider](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Arcstrider) sub-class in Destiny 2, has a number of different moves available when using the super.

Is there a list of specific moves and combinations of strikes to better understand what is possible, or is it just a matter of lots of primary attacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ironically, I've linked to the very page I was looking for.

[This page about Arcstaff](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Arc_Staff), lists some combinations.

> Combos
>   In the following sections, **R1 = Light Attack** and **R2 = Heavy
>   Attack** (on PC, these are bound by default to LMB and RMB,
>   respectively). Light Attacks consume a small chunk of super energy
>   while Heavy Attacks consume a larger chunk of super energy.
>
> R1: Basic attack.
>   R2: Unleash a destructive wave of energy that travels along the ground.
>   R1, R2: Basic attack followed by an uppercut.
>   R1, R1, R1: Basic combo with light conal damage.
>   R1, R1, R2:
>   Basic combo with a heavy conal finisher.
>   R2 while airborne: Heavy
>   downward smash. Radial area-of-effect damage centered on the point of
>   impact.